# BigDecimalRange validator is not working in vaadin 8 (Binder)

Tags: java, textfield, bigdecimal, vaadin8, android-binder

BigDecimalRange validator is not working in vaadin version  **8.4.3** we tried to change to the latest version of vaadin 8 but the problem persist . Error shows withValidator  like *renaming the file* ,What will be the problem and how can I fix this,Iam trying  to change vaadin 7 TextField to  vaadin 8 .In v7 it was working fine. Please help

```
binder.forField(txtAmnt)
.asRequired("This field is mandatory")
.withValidator(new BigDecimalRangeValidator("Enter an amount",BigDecimal.ZERO,new BigDecimal("1000")))
.bind(amount);
```

Comment: If your txtAmnt is a `TextField` you need converter as well, `StringToBigDecimalConverter`.

Comment: can you please explain with an example?

Answer (score 0):

If your txtAmnt is a `TextField` you need converter using `withConverter` as well, `StringToBigDecimalConverter`. You need to set converter before the `withValidator` as it assumes `BigDecimal` type, which is not compatible with String emitted by `TextField`.

```
binder.forField(txtAmnt)
    .asRequired("This field is mandatory")
    .withConverter(new StringToBigDecimalConverter("Error converting to 
            BigDecimal")
    .withValidator(new BigDecimalRangeValidator("Enter an 
            amount",BigDecimal.ZERO,new BigDecimal("1000")))
    .bind(amount);
```